# For XML in SQL Server - adding Child elements

Tags: sql, xml, for-xml

I have this following query

[image]

Returns this XML File Format

[image]

How Can I get it in this format?

[image]

Please Help, 
source Code

```
SELECT top 1

    (SELECT top 1
    count(*)AS 'number-of-accounts', 
    sum(br.cnsmr_accnt_bckt_crrnt_bal_amnt) AS 'total-value-of-account-payment',
    '' AS 'date-of-turnover',
    '' AS 'is-conversion-job'
    FROM
    cnsmr as c
    inner join cnsmr_accnt as ca ON c.cnsmr_id = ca.cnsmr_id
    inner join cnsmr_accnt_bckt_bal_rprtng as br on ca.cnsmr_accnt_id = br.cnsmr_accnt_id
     FOR XML PATH('payment-import-header'), TYPE),

    (SELECT  top 1
    br.cnsmr_accnt_bckt_crrnt_bal_amnt AS 'payment-amount',
    '' AS 'bucket-transaction-type',
    '' AS 'tendered-date',
    '' AS 'entered-date',
    '' AS 'payment-location-code',
    '' AS 'payment-memo-code',
    '' AS 'payment-comments',
    '' AS 'external-reference-identifier'

    FROM
    cnsmr as c
    inner join cnsmr_accnt as ca ON c.cnsmr_id = ca.cnsmr_id
    inner join cnsmr_accnt_bckt_bal_rprtng as br on ca.cnsmr_accnt_id = br.cnsmr_accnt_id

    FOR XML PATH('consumer-payment'), ROOT('consumer-payment-import'),TYPE)

FOR XML RAW (''), ROOT ('consumer-payment-import-job'), ELEMENTS XSINIL;
```

Comment: Copy/paste your code *into your question*.  Do *not* upload pictures of code.  We can't do anything with a picture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please tag with the actual RDBMS (product and version). Syntax and pictures point to SQL-Server...

Please read [How to ask a good SQL question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056)  and [How to create a MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Without test data I cannot test this, but the following should help...

```
SELECT top 1

    (SELECT top 1
    count(*)AS 'number-of-accounts', 
    sum(br.cnsmr_accnt_bckt_crrnt_bal_amnt) AS 'total-value-of-account-payment',
    '' AS 'date-of-turnover',
    '' AS 'is-conversion-job'
    FROM
    cnsmr as c
    inner join cnsmr_accnt as ca ON c.cnsmr_id = ca.cnsmr_id
    inner join cnsmr_accnt_bckt_bal_rprtng as br on ca.cnsmr_accnt_id = br.cnsmr_accnt_id
     FOR XML PATH('payment-import-header'), TYPE),

    (SELECT  top 1
    br.cnsmr_accnt_bckt_crrnt_bal_amnt AS 'payment-amount',
    '' AS 'bucket-transaction-type',
    '' AS 'tendered-date',
    '' AS 'entered-date',
    '' AS 'payment-location-code',
    '' AS 'payment-memo-code',
    '' AS 'payment-comments',
    '' AS 'external-reference-identifier'
    ,(
        SELECT 'SomeValue' AS Something
        FOR XML PATH('consumer-identifier'),TYPE
     )
    FROM
    cnsmr as c
    inner join cnsmr_accnt as ca ON c.cnsmr_id = ca.cnsmr_id
    inner join cnsmr_accnt_bckt_bal_rprtng as br on ca.cnsmr_accnt_id = br.cnsmr_accnt_id

    FOR XML PATH('consumer-payment'), ROOT('consumer-payment-import'),TYPE) AS [consumer-payment-imports]

FOR XML RAW (''), ROOT ('consumer-payment-import-job'), ELEMENTS XSINIL;
```

The `AS [consumer-payment-imports]` will wrap the whole inner node within one more node.

The second addition is one more sub-select to add your customer-reference into the inner sub-select. If this is not `1:n` it might be enough to use

```
'SomeValue' AS [consumer-identifier/Something]
```

This will add the value `SomeValue` within a nested element...